# Is it possible to show progress with rsync by folder?

Tags: rsync

I'm looking for a way to show rsync's progress by folder, instead of by file (rsync -P) or by overall progress (rsync --info=progress2). Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I think 'overall progress (rsync --info=progress2)' is the best option. Folders can contain very different amount of data, so it would not be a good help for predicting remaining time.

Comment: In this case, each folder represents a block of data that could be used once the folder copy process has been done, so getting feedback that it's done copying would allow me to start using that data right away.

Comment: I see. One way would be to do it with a `for` loop over the directory trees and write some output when copying each directory tree is done. `rsync` can still do the copying.

Comment: I made a demo example with a shellscript for you. Instead of a `for` loop I use `find` which has more powerful methods for this purpose. It think it will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo system for you and tested it in a test environment. Your real case is probably different, and the main difference may be that you are copying to another drive or even another computer, at least if the copying is a backup.

It should be fairly easy to modify the following shellscript to fix your real case.

```
#!/bin/bash

tdir="$(pwd)"
tdir="${tdir##*/}"
if [ "$tdir" != "work" ]
then
 pwd
 echo "You should change current directory to \"work\" and try again"
 exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" == "-n" ] || [ "$1" == "dry-run" ]
then
 find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -exec echo -e "------------------------------------------\ncopy of {}:" \; \
  -exec rsync -avn {} ../backup \;
elif [ "$1" == "do-it" ]
then
 find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -exec rsync -a {} ../backup \; -exec echo "copy of {} finished" \;
else
 echo "Work in a directory structure with a work directory containing a set of
directories, and a backup directory alongside the work directory,
for example:

$ find | sort
.
./backup
./work
./work/dir1
./work/dir1/file1
./work/dir1/file2
./work/dir1/file 3
./work/dir2
./work/dir2/file1
./work/dir2/file2
./work/dir3
./work/dir3/file1
./work/dir3/file2
./work/dir3/file3
./work/dir 4
./work/dir 4/file 1
./work/file1
./work/file2
./work/rsync-by-folder"
 read -p "-----------------------Press Enter to continue"
 echo "
Usage:

$0 [-h]           # Show this help output

$0 -n             # Dry run only showing what would be done
$0 dry-run        # Dry run only showing what would be done

$0 do-it          # Run the real copying process
"
fi
```

Edit: If you wish, you can add the `rsync` option `--info=progress2` onto the 'do-it' command line.